# Does the String argument to PageStorageKey really matter?

Tags: flutter

When Supplying a PageStorageKey, does it really matter what the argument value is?

Asking another way, are two instances of PageStorageKey with the same string argument unique or equivalent?

In other languages, things like this use their storage reference to disambiguate, so the actual text linked to the object doesn't matter.

I'm trying to determine if I need to ensure that all PageStorageKeys in my application have to have unique strings as a seed, or can I just boilerplate them all to the same value?

```
var psKey1 = PageStorageKey<String>('Am I the same or different than my sibling?');
var psKey2 = PageStorageKey<String>('Am I the same or different than my sibling?');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears two PageStorageKeys with the same String initializer are considered the same.

I wrote a short example and ran it under debugging

Test 1

```
    var psKey1 = PageStorageKey('am I a clone');
    var psKey2 = PageStorageKey('am I a clone');
    var equivalent = psKey1 == psKey2;
```

equivalent = true;

Test 2

```
    var psKey1 = PageStorageKey('am I a clone');
    var psKey2 = PageStorageKey('am I not a clone');
    var equivalent = psKey1 == psKey2;
```

equivalent = false;

I will be proceeeding under the presumption that all PageStorageKeys need to be unique within a given scope.